# Add a Block ABOVE view

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I need to add short descriptions for some 20+ views and display them above the views. I know I have an option to add a header to a view, but that's not what I want. I have a sidebar on the left and the main content on the right which displays views on the views pages. I need to add different descriptions for my views ABOVE both sidebar and main content.

How do I achieve it?

Comment: Have you tried creating a block and placing it in a region in `/admin/structure/block` ?

Comment: Yes. The thing is, I need different content in this block depending on the current view. So I'd need to create 20+ different blocks for each of my views which seems redundant. I'm sure there must be more elegant solution.

Comment: 1. In "Header" you have option to use tokens if you need different description depending on view content. 2. If that does not solve your problem, are you okay with a solution where you have to write custom code in your theme template file ?

Comment: 1. You mean view header? I know. But I need this content to appear not in the view header, but in the region above the view. 2. Yes I am.

Comment: Have you already tried adding code in template file ? May I know what did you try ? Or If you can be more specific about your need(what exactly should be in description you want), then I may try helping with code.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes. The thing is, I need different content in this block depending on
>   the current view. So I'd need to create 20+ different blocks for each
>   of my views which seems redundant. I'm sure there must be more elegant
>   solution.

Create a block and use [template_preprocess_block](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7.x) to alter the content based on the path. In your theme's **template.php** add:

```
mytheme_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['block']->bid === 'target_block_id') {
    $path = current_path(); // gets the current page path. 

    switch($path) {
      case path1: 
         $vars['content'] = "Hello World";
         break;
      case path2: 
         $vars['content'] = "Hello Kitty";
         break;
       // ... and so on and so forth.
    }

  }
}
```

<sub>**Note:** replace `mytheme` with your actual theme name, same for `'target_block_id'`.</sub>

---

Another possible option, would be to add a header to your views, and then just use CSS with absolute position to move it, this would mean you'll need to add some `padding-top:` or `padding-bottom` on some other div to create a space for it.